# Composite app without PRISM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, prism

I have a relatively big app. After I reviewed a UI design offered by a UI designer I noticed that each View is divided into 3 parts: top, middle, bottom.

The top part always displays current date and time. It also has two text blocks, one of which is displayed always and the second depends on what user do in the middle part of a View.

The middle part is the main content part, from one view to another this part changes significantly.

The bottom part is a navigation panel in point of fact. It changes but not so much. It consists of a couple of buttons.

Well, when I started to think I realized that I don't want to create many Windows (Views), especially because of the fact that one of the middle parts from the offered design has a TabControl which in turn has very similar content in all it's tabs!

So, if I understand rightly, I need to create only one View (in very deed I need to create a bit more, but that is not important) and many UserControls. The View (it's ViewModel) should change (inject to) the content of the middle and the bottom parts to different UserControls. As I understand this is the concept of a Composite Application.

Am I right? How to accomplish such a task? Can I avoid PRISM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism is a good way to go because of region controller and it gives everything you need out of the box. Yet, if you wish to avoid it - create three contentControls which will serve as top, middle, bottom regions. Make them accessable through some "Controller" like

```
MyController.AddContentToTopRegion(UserControl uc)
```

Thus will allow you to have a domain which is responsible for regions and you can inject views  on the runtime.